# My navbar stopped working with bootstrap 5 and html?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

My navbar just stopped working out of nowhere and now I dont see my background image, my text on the background image and my nav, everything just became white after I started adding the links to my different href. I also use bootstrap 5.The only thing that I can see is from my id citation and after... before it shows a white box. (It was working fine before)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-default">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link link-light active" href="">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link link-light active" href="">
                    À PROPOS
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link link-light dropdown-toggle" role="button" 
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" >
                    INFORMATION
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" 
                        href="">
                            Définition
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" 
                        href="">
                            Type de cyberattaques
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" 
                        href="">
                            Grandes compagnies
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link link-light active" href="">CONTACTER</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/code.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <title>TP 2</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="main_page" style="background-image:url(/Site_web/html_projet/img/Home-bg.jpg)" 
    class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h1 class="text-light">Cybersecurité</h1>
        <h4 class="text-light">Une intro à la cybersécurité par Enrique Crossier</h4>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container-fluid" id="citation">
        <div class="p-5">
            <h1 class="fw-bold">
                «En 2019, plus de 3 millions de nouveaux virus sont créés par
                jour, la cybersécurité est primordiale!»<br>
            </h1>
            <h3 class="text-secondary"> - Karim Ganame</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="p-5">
            <h1 class="fw-bold">
                «Le plus puissant des antivirus est celui qui se trouve derrière
                son écran et son clavier» <br>
            </h1>
            <h3 class="text-secondary"> - Samy Mahfoudh</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <a href="Information/Définition.html" class="btn btn-success">Pour en savoir plus</a>
        </div>
    </div>
      
</body>
```

Comment: If that's the exact markup you're using, it's invalid - the navbar needs to be inside the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to work when I tried it with bootstrap 5.

Try changing "text-light" and "link-light" to "text-dark" and "link-dark".
The text colour is white and the background is white so you can't see it.

As for the image link, check that it is correct. I can't help with that because I don't know the structure of your website.